# Is there a way to change leaflet-gpx style?

Tags: leaflet, gpx

I'm using the [leaflet-gpx](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx) plugin to draw various .gpx files on my map.
How can I change the color/style of it?

```
gpxvar[{{loop.index0}}] = new L.GPX("{{url_for('static', filename='gpx/' + r )}}", {
        async: true,
        marker_options: {
            startIconUrl: "{{url_for('static', filename='img/pin-icon-start.png')}}",
            endIconUrl: "{{url_for('static', filename='img/pin-icon-end.png')}}",
            shadowUrl: "{{url_for('static', filename='img/pin-shadow.png')}}"
        }
```

gpxvar is my L.GPX object, I tried the below code but it didn't change anything, any pointers?

```
var highlightStyle = {
    color: '#9b1d41',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.6,
    fillOpacity: 0.65,
    fillColor: '#9b1d41'
};
    gpxvar[{{loop.index0}}].setStyle(highlightStyle);
```

Comment: it might have to do with the order i do things as once the page is loaded, doing a gpxvar[0].setStyle({color: 'red'}) changes well the color....

Answer (score 1):

ok it seems like as L.GPX extends L.featureGroup and that the latter has a setStyle method, one should just have to pass it while creating it.
looking at [the code](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx/blob/master/gpx.js) it defaults to blue using `polyline_options`

so my code added it and I got different colors now :

```
var colors = ['red', 'purple'];
gpxvar[{{loop.index0}}] = new L.GPX("{{url_for('static', filename='gpx/' + r )}}", {
        async: true,
        marker_options: {
            startIconUrl: "{{url_for('static', filename='img/pin-icon-start.png')}}",
            endIconUrl: "{{url_for('static', filename='img/pin-icon-end.png')}}",
            shadowUrl: "{{url_for('static', filename='img/pin-shadow.png')}}"
        },
        polyline_options: {color: colors[{{loop.index0}}]}

    })
```